# How to divide each column with a different number

Tags: r

I used the "table" function of R to summarize data and got the following result:

Summarized Data

[image]

Now, I want to divide all the numbers in the first column with 32, all the numbers in the second column with 51, and all the numbers in the third column with 54. Then these numbers will form a new 3*5 matrix, and I'll use the new matrix to continue to draw a barplot.

Does anyone here know how I can write the command in R?

Comment: Please do not share code or data as images, some people will not be able to see them and it is much more work for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `col` to replicate the `vector` of values to make the lengths same and then do the division

```
out/c(32, 51, 54)[col(out)]
```

Or just transpose the output, do the division and transpose

```
t(t(out)/c(32, 51, 54))
```

---

If we take a reproducible example

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3]

col(df1) # gives the column index
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    1    2    3
#[3,]    1    2    3
```

In `R`, the indexing starts from 1. As these index are repeated, when we pass a `vector` of values equal to the total number of columns, each of the value gets replicated

```
v1 <- c(32, 51, 54)
v1[col(df1)]
#[1] 32 32 32 51 51 51 54 54 54
```

The lengths are now the same

```
df1/v1[col(df1)]
#                  mpg        cyl     disp
#Mazda RX4     0.65625 0.11764706 2.962963
#Mazda RX4 Wag 0.65625 0.11764706 2.962963
#Datsun 710    0.71250 0.07843137 2.000000
```

checking the output by individually dividing

```
df1[,1]/32
#[1] 0.65625 0.65625 0.71250
```

For the second solution, by doing the `t`ranspose, we make use of the recycling

```
t(df1)/v1
#     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710
#mpg  0.6562500     0.6562500 0.71250000
#cyl  0.1176471     0.1176471 0.07843137
#disp 2.9629630     2.9629630 2.00000000
```

As the output is transposed, we do a second `t`ranspose to get the original data structure

Comment: Sorry, do you mind giving more details of this solution? I'm really a newbie of learning R and I couldn't understand command you provide. Thank you.

Comment: Just did that. The system asked me to wait for five minutes before I could click the "accept".

Comment: @davidchen thanks, I added some expalantion, hope it helps. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure it out how to work on my data.

Answer (score 0):

```
testMartix = dataframe(matrix(seq(1:100), nrow = 5, ncol = 20))
print(testMartix)
divisors = c(32, 51, 54)
new.matrix = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 3))
new.matrix

i=1
for (i in 1:3){
  print(i)
  new.matrix[,i] = testMartix[,i]/divisors[i]
  i = i+1
}
```

Akrun's way is better. BUT, this is kind of intuative. it boils down to:

```
print(testMartix[,1]/divisors[1])
print(testMartix[,2]/divisors[2])
print(testMartix[,3]/divisors[3])
```

Comment: Np buddy. hope you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sweep` :

```
sweep(data,2,c(32, 51, 54), `/`)
```